# Broken Random PHP

Tags: php, random, seed

I have been using mt_rand(10,100) to get a random number between 10 and 100 but it gives me 74 every time.

Heres what im working with

```
$success=mt_rand(10,100);
```

Any ideas ? Do i need to seed somehow ? Thanks in advance.

---EDIT---

I have just tried this

```
    srand(microtime());
    $success=rand(10,100);
```

Still gives same answer every time, 47.

---EDIT---

this is the whole thing

```
srand(microtime());
$success=rand(10,100);
echo $success;
if ($success == 100) {
    $displayline="You succeeded";
    session_register("displayline");
    header("location:userhome.php");
}
```

Comment: You may need to show more code. As I ran that in a loop, and received many different random numbers, as expected. In fact, in a loop of 50, I did not receive 1 `74`. This was on PHP 5.3

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using? Do you seed the generator manually?

Comment: I would think that it is being reset somewhere down the line. Did you have a test case somewhere you forgot to remove?

Comment: I have to agree with @nikic, I would venture to say you're calling `mt_srand` with a fixed number. As of php v4.2.0 there is no need to seed the random number generator.

Comment: when i use mt_rand it always gives 74 when i supply the arguments (10,100) and always 47 when i supply the same into rand.

Comment: @Trent Post all of your code so we can see what's going on.

Comment: That is odd.  It would be funny if this wound up on ServerFault.

Comment: The only other thing is an if statement that follows to check if the number is 100 and to echo $success

Comment: Potentially relevant: http://xkcd.com/221/

Answer (score 1):

What version of PHP are you running?  In 4.2.0, mt_rand() was changed to be seeded automatically.

You can seed it with mt_srand($seed), providing a seed value.  I use the output of the microtime() function.

**edit:** Since you are on 5.2, check your code to see if mt_srand() is being called and comment out all such calls.

Comment: @Trent: Have you made absolutely sure, that you do **NOT** seed the generator?

Comment: @Trent In that case you need to show more code.  It could be something you're just not seeing.  Alternatively, have you tried the code on another system?

Answer (score 0):

That's odd.  If you do just `mt_rand()` what do you get?  What's the value for `mt_getrandmax()`?

Try seeding it with `mt_srand()`

Answer (score 0):

It seeds on itself.

http://www.suspekt.org/2008/08/17/mt_srand-and-not-so-random-numbers/

Guess you should check your PHP version

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the seeding functions and don't add them back in. Then restart your server.

Also, I found [this PHP bug](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=26381), which occurs on Windows systems with some versions of the php.ini file.

Comment: @Trent Did you figure out what was causing it?